# Adding data to a DB using an Angular 2 service, UI not refreshing

Tags: post, service, angular

First timer here....be gentle.  I've searched quite a bit and didn't find anything that specifically seemed to address this problem.  We have adopted Angular2 for a Singe Page Application.  I have a page that has a data entry block with a grid below it.  The page calls a "get" service to fill the grid upon loading.  Clicking the submit button in the data entry area calls an "add" service that executes a stored proc and inserts the data into a postgre sql db.  All good.  Except, I'm struggling to get the grid to refresh to show the row that was newly added (even tried calling the "Get" service after the "Add").  All of the examples I've seen to date only use local arrays as the data stores (pop, push to manipulate the data).  As our data is being persisted in a database, these examples don't quite get me all the way there.  IContent is an interface that models the data.   _contentList is an array of IContent and populated by the "Get" service.  Any help appreciated!

> Update:  per JB's suggestion, I commented out the caching code in the get service and added an explicit call to the get service following the add >service call. Still got the same behavior.

MainComponent:

```
import {Component}     from 'angular2/core';
import {IContent} from '../../classes/interfaces';
import {ContentService} from '../../services/content.service';
...
import {OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {ControlGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from 'angular2/common';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Component({
    selector: 'view',
    templateUrl: 'src/views/the-view.html',
    providers: [ContentService],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, MdToolbar, MdButton, MdCard, MD_LIST_DIRECTIVES, MdInput],
})

export class ContentMgmtComponent {

    public _contentList: IContent[];
    myForm: ControlGroup;
    contentAdded: boolean = false;


        constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder, private _contentService: ContentService) {

        // Programmatically build out form
        this.myForm = _formBuilder.group(
            {
                pageID: ["", Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
                zoneID: ["", Validators.required],
                contentText: ["", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(10)])],
                startDate: ["", Validators.required],
                endDate: ["", Validators.required]
        });

        // Get existing pages / content 
        this._contentService.getAllContent()
            .subscribe((content: IContent[]) => {
                this._contentList = content[0]["contentInfo"];
            });


    }

    //Add the new content to the database.
    onAddContentClick(pageId: string, zoneId: string, contentText: string, startDate: string, endDate: string) {

        this._contentService.addContent(pageId, zoneId, contentText, startDate, endDate)
        this.contentAdded = true;

        // *** PROBLEM BE HERE ... tried calling the Get Service, etc. ***


    }

 }
```

Portion of the the-view.html that should refresh:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading"><h4>Nova Custom Content Manager</h4>    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="col-md-12 table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Content Id</th>
                    <th>Page Id</th>
                    <th>Zone Id</th>
                    <th>Content</th>
                    <th>Active FL</th>
                    <th>Start Date</th>
                    <th>End Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="info" *ngFor="#contentItem of _contentList">
                    <td>{{contentItem.contentID}}</td>
                    <td>{{contentItem.pageID}}</td>
                    <td>{{contentItem.zoneID}}</td>
                    <td>{{contentItem.contentText}}</td>
                    <td>{{contentItem.activeFlag}}</td>
                    <td>{{contentItem.startDate}}</td>
                    <td>{{contentItem.endDate}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Services:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {IContent} from '../classes/interfaces';
import {Observer} from 'rxjs/Observer';


@Injectable()
export class ContentService {

    content: IContent[];    //returned by the actual service call to the consumer


    constructor(private http: Http) { 
    }

    addContent(_pageId: string, _zoneId: string, _content: string, _startDate: string, _endDate: string) {
        let body = JSON.stringify({ pageID: _pageId, zoneID: _zoneId, contentText: _content, activeFlag: "true", startDate: _startDate, endDate: _endDate });
        let headers = new Headers({ 'content-type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        this.http.post('http://whereever.com/api/addcontent', body, options)
            .subscribe(
            data => console.log(data),
            err => console.log(err.json().message),
            () => console.log('Authentication Complete')
        );
    }

    getAllContent(): Observable<IContent[]> {
        if (!this.content) {
            //return this.http.get("/src/services/content.json")
            return     this.http.get("http://whereever.com/api/getallcontents")
                .map((res: Response) => {
                    this.content = res.json();
                    return this.content;
                })
                .catch(this.handleError);
        }
        else {
            //return cached data
            return this.createObservable(this.content);
        }
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        if (res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
          throw new Error('Bad response status: ' + res.status);
        }
        let body = res.json();
        return body.data || { };
    }

**strong text**...


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service returns cached data. It shouldn't.

Make it make an http request **every time** it's called, not just the first time. Otherwise, obviously, it always returns the same, stale data.

Comment: JB: even if I comment out the caching code in the Get, it still doesn't refresh after the add...even with a get called explicitly after the add.

Comment: Then update your question with the updated code. There's probably something else that is wrong.

Comment: You're still returning cached data. And the controller still doesn't call your service after the post. Remove the `content`field in the service. Remove the if/else in the method. Add the code used to refresh the data. That's where the whole problem is. Hint: you must refresh the data **after** the post has **succeeded**.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, but you are replacing your content list from that returned by the service. Maybe try clearing your bound list and adding the content returned from the service. I'm assuming that the binding to the list will not work if you replace the entire list with a new instance.

this._contentList = content[0]["contentInfo"]; // clear this._contentList and rebuild it from content[0]["contentInfo"]